# meaning of the phrase "go for something right about now"?

Tags: meaning

I have happened upon it in [Crash Course Anatomy & Phisiology](https://youtu.be/mFm3yA1nslE). The phrase is at around 6 minute and 44 second. Here is the context:

> Speaking of what and where your taste buds really are, you know what I could **go for right about now**? A debunking!

I know what the phrases *go for* and *right now* mean, but what is the word *about* there for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Particularly when referring to times, [**about**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/about) can mean "nearly; almost".  If I say, "I'll be there at about three o'clock," then I am not promising to arrive at exactly 3:00, but I will be there not too long before or after three.

So "right **about** now" softens the "right now" from meaning "at this instant in time" into something  a little more relaxed.  It feels more like "very soon" and is not as urgent as "right now."  It also has a fairly informal register because it mixes an intensifying word (right) with a word that softens the intensity (about), which is a bit logically contradictory. You probably would not see this phrase in formal writing.

That said, **right about now** is a fairly common set phrase and a lot of English speakers will use it without thinking very hard about whether it means anything different from **now**. It's more likely to signal informality than anything else.

One other way you'll sometimes hear this phrase in spoken English is with a big pause in it:

> Right about...[pause]...now!

Often, the vowel in "about" will be drawn out as well.  This is used when the speaker knows something is going to happen in just a few seconds.  They say, "right abouuuuuut..." to signify the "very soon," and then shout, "now!" when the thing actually happens.